# docker-compose up -d failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wrote a simple docker-compose.yml as bellow,

```
version: '3'
services:
  ubuntu:
    container_name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu

  debian:
    container_name: debian
    image: debian
```

then ran

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

finally I got two containers with exited status.
[image]

even I typed

```
$ docker start <container_id>
```

trying to make containers running, but still fail.

Anyone tell me how to fix my yaml file, to make this two containers run with 'docker-compose up -d' ?

Comment: Just running a bare `debian` or `ubuntu` container won't really do anything.  You should generally think of a container as a wrapper around a single process; you'll need to build a Docker _image_ that contains it.  Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entrypoint and command for these 2 docker images `ubuntu` and `debian` will not do anything that keep the container running.

In case you want them to keep running, you can modify your `docker-compose` file like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  ubuntu:
    container_name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
    command:
      - |
        tail -f /dev/null

  debian:
    container_name: debian
    image: debian
    entrypoint:
      - bash
      - -c
    command:
      - |
        tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: I'm sorry that, Mr. Nguyen Lam Phuc, I am not familiar bout the functions of stack overflow, maybe I mis-touch some where XD.
trying to vote positive but fail now  QQ

Comment: No worries @magicpony. It may take time to get used to :)